# Structuring a large vue project

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, vue.js, structure

I have a method in my vuejs project call getInstagram().

It's a about 50 lines of code which updates the DOM on a main index page with instagram pics. I would like to take it out of the main app.js file to tidy it up a bit.

What are my options?

a) ES2015 module (it still has to be a vuejs method)

b) Vue component(there is no markup so this seem wrong)

At the moment option A is the front runner or something else?

```
import {instagram} from './social.js';

      getInstagram:function(num_photos) {
        instagram();
      },
```

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without seeing you code, but I would use a [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is ideal.